# Make palindromic string non-palindromic by rearranging its letters

Tags: c++, algorithm

Q: Make palindromic string non-palindromic by rearranging its letters.

I just want to know why my solution is failing (wrong answer) for some test cases when i submit the code. I am sure there is an easy solution such as sorting the whole string?

```
void makeNonPalindrome(string& s)
{
    bool ans = false;
    int l = s.length();
    if(l % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int i = l/2; i < l; i++)
        {
            if(s[l/2 - 1] != s[i])
            {
                swap(&s[l/2 - 1],&s[i]);
                ans = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(!ans)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < l/2-1; i++)
            {
                if(s[l/2 - 1] != s[i])
                {
                    ans = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = l/2 + 1; i < l; i++)
        {
            if(s[l/2 - 1] != s[i])
            {
                swap(&s[l/2 - 1],&s[i]);
                ans = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(!ans)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < l/2-1; i++)
            {
                if(s[l/2 - 1] != s[i])
                {
                    ans = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!ans)
        {
            if(s[l/2] != s[0])
            {
                swap(&s[l/2],&s[0]);
                ans = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ans)
        cout << s << '\n';
    else
        cout << -1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what algorithm or idea you're trying to do with this code?   Does what you're trying to do have a name that is familiar to us, and you're just not implementing it correctly?

Comment: What should this line do? `swap(&s[l/2 - 1],&s[i]);` What swap function is it?

Comment: Please, try rearranging the letters of `"AAA"` so it's no longer a palindrome.

Comment: You say "rearrange", but that can be done any multiple of ways.  Why did you feel the need to come up something that looks so complex?  A simple call to [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) would have also worked in rearranging the letters.  If not that, write code that does what `std::partition` does.

Comment: your code fails for some test cases, because it outputs something that is not accepted as correct result. I am really sorry, but there are many questions of this kind and the solution is always the same: You need to find a test case that fails. Unless you know the input that produces wrong output, you cannot fix it. Afaik there is no magic way to generate test input, but you need to be creative, try corner cases until you find one that makes your test fail

Comment: Is this a hackerrank question or something similar? If so, a link will clear up some of the confusion for posters.

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging a palindrome so it become non-palindromic can be done quite fast, by simply trying to swap two adjacent letters in the string if they are different.
For instance, in `'bob'`, you'd need to find the first distinct adjacent letters (that is `b` and `o` in our case), and swap them. The result would then be `'obb'`, which is not a palindrome.

```
void makeNonPalindrome(std::string& s) {
    char tmp;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i+1]) {  // then swap s[i] and s[i+1]
            tmp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[i+1];
            s[i+1] = tmp;
            std::cout << s << '\n';
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << -1 << '\n';
}
```

This is a simpler way to make a palindrome non palindromic.
NB: this function assumes that the input is indeed a palindrome, so if you feed it a string like `'oob'`, it will output `'bob'` which is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input palindrome `string s` you can just use [`find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to determine if the string can be rearranged into a non-palindrome at all, *and* if so what characters should be swapped to do this. For example:

```
const auto foo = s.find_first_not_of(s[0], 1);
```

If `foo == string::npos` it means that there isn't a possible non-palindrome rearrangement. Otherwise `swap(s[0], s[foo])` will break the palindrome.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/T3d8Fc)